# Is it better to have 1 or 10 output neurons?

Tags: neural-network

Is it better to have:

1 output neuron that outputs a value between 0 and 15 which would be my ultimate value

or

16 output neurons that output a value between 0 and 1 which represents the propability for this value?

Example: We want to find out the grade (ranging from 0 to 15) a student gets by inputing the number of hours he learned and his IQ.

Comment: 16 neurons would be better, this allows for better designs.

Comment: Thank you. One more question: What do you mean with designs?

Comment: Maybe a simple example could be you are creating a neural network to recognize digits (0 - 9) you can have 10 output neurons. You then want to expand the network for Hex. Now you need 16 classes from (0 - F). It will be easier to change from 10 to 16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR: I think your problem would be better framed as a regression task, so use one ouptut neuron, but it is worth to try both.**

I don't quite like the broadness of your question in contrast to the very specific answers, so I am going to go a little deeper and explain what exactly should be the proper formulation.

Before we start, we should clarify the two big tasks that classical Artificial Neural Networks perform:

1. Classification
2. Regression

They are [inherently very different from one another](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141381/regression-vs-classification); in short, Classification tries to *put a label on your input* (e.g., the input image shows a *dog*), whereas regression tries to predict a numerical value (e.g., the input data corresponds to a house that has an *estimated worth of 1.5 million $US*).
Obviously, you can see that predicting the numerical value requires (trivially) only *one* output value. Also note that this is only true for **this specific example**. There could be other regression usecases, in which you want your output to have more than 0 dimensions (i.e. a single point), but instead be 1D, or 2D. 
A common example would for example be [Image Colorization](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/reports/2016/pdfs/219_Report.pdf), which we can interestingly enough also frame as a classification problem. The provided link shows examples for both. In this case you would obviously have to regress (or classify) every pixel, which leads to more than one output neuron.

Now, to get to your actual question, I want to elaborate a little more on the reasoning why one-hot encoded outputs (i.e. output with as many channels as classes) are preferred **for classification tasks** over a single neuron.
Since we could argue that a single neuron is enough to predict the class value, we have to understand why it is problematic to get to a specific class that way.

#### [Categorical vs Ordinal vs Interval Variables](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/whatstat/what-is-the-difference-between-categorical-ordinal-and-interval-variables/)

One of the main problems is the *type* of your variable. In your case, there exists a clear order (15 is better than 14 is better than 13, etc.), and even an interval ordering (at least on paper), since the difference between a 15 and 13 is the same as between 14 and 12, although some scholars might argue against that ;-)
Thus, your target is an interval variable, and could thus be in theory used to regress on it. More on that later. But consider for example a variable that describes whether the image depicts a cat (0), dog (1), or car (2). Now, arguably, we cannot even order the variables (is a car > dog, or car < dog?), nor can we say that there exists an "equal distance" between a cat and a dog (similar, since both are animals?) or a cat and a car (arguably more different from each other). Thus, it becomes really hard to interpret a single output value of the network. Say an input image results in the output of, say, 1.4.
Does this now still correspond to a dog, or is this closer to a car? But what if the image actually depicts a car that has [properties of a cat](https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-KJfevJKhqnU/T-v4fJ6iOwI/AAAAAAAAGH8/pKyLYLa0SOU/s1600/the-pink-funny-car-cat-costume-02.jpg)?
On the other hand, having 3 separate neurons that reflect the different probabilities of each class eliminate that problem, since each one can depict a relatively "undisturbed" probability.

#### How to Loss Function

The other problem is the question how to backpropagate through the network in the previous example. Classically, classification tasks make use of [Cross-Entropy Loss](https://ml-cheatsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/loss_functions.html) (CE), whereas regression uses Mean Squared Error (MSE) as a measure. Those two are inherently different, and especially the combination of CE and [Softmax](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/multi-class-neural-networks/softmax) lead to very [convenient (and stable) derivations](https://deepnotes.io/softmax-crossentropy). 
Arguably, you could apply rounding to get from 1.4 to a concise class value (in that case, 1) and then use CE loss, but that would maybe lead to numerically instability; MSE on the other hand will never give you a "clear class value", but more a regressed estimate.

In the end, the question boils down to: **Do I have a classification or regression problem**. In your case, I would argue that both approaches could work reasonably well. A (classification) network might not recognize the correlation between the different output classes; i.e. a student that has a high likelihood for class 14 basically has zero probability of scoring a 3 or lower. On the other hand, regression might not be able to accurately predict the results for other reasons.
If you have the time, I would highly encourage you to try both approaches. For now, considering the interval type of your target, I would personally go with a regression task, and use rounding *after you have trained your network* and can make accurate predictions.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to have a single neuron for each class (except binary classification). This allows for better design in terms of expanding upon an existing design. A simple example is creating a network for recognizing digits 0 through 9, but then changing the design to hex from 0 through F.

Comment: Keep in mind that this is very different from popular classification tasks like MNIST, where different classes have little to do with each other. This task, on the other hand, is very specifically asking for an interval type, so regression makes absolutely sense here. "Changing the design" is also not something very likely to happen in this scenario, unless you change your grade scale. But then again, I think the retraining is only an aspect for large networks anyways.

Comment: It is possible you are correct, however building a neural network has nothing to do with training, nor for particular datasets. Here I am simply trying to explain that having the structure of a network with 10 output layers might be better since you can change the network if the problem changes or simply use the existing network as a guide to creating a new network for a problem that requires a different amount of classes. The question is not clear if it is regression or a classification problem.

Comment: Exactly. But then simply suggesting Classification without any background is not really the way to go. And you can also retrain your regression network to fit to a new range, same as you would have to retrain with more classes...

Comment: That's probably a fair assessment.