# Activation function to get day of week

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence, activation-function

I'm writing a program to predict when will something happens. I don't know which activation function to get output in day of week (1-7).

I tried sigmoid function but i need to input the predicted day and it output probability of it, I don't want it to be this way.

I expect the activation function returning 0 to infinite, is ReLU the best activation function for this task?

**EDIT:**

also, what if i wanted output more than 7 days, for example, x will hapen in 9th day from today, or 15th day from today, etc? I'm looking for dynamic ways to do this

Comment: how about having 7 output nodes with softmax activation ? the one which gives the maximum probability is the right one

Comment: that would work too, but i just want 1 output node, is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to add onto the point of @venkata krishnan, which raises a valid point in your problem setting. You will find an answer to your original question further down, but I strongly suggeste you read the following comment first.

Generally, you want to discern between categorical, ordinal and interval variables. I have given a relatively lengthy explanation in [a different answer on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51954704/is-it-better-to-have-1-or-10-output-neurons/51961595#51961595), it might be helpful to understand this concept in more detail. 
In your scenario, you mostly want to have an understanding of "*how wrong*" you are. Of course, it is perfectly reasonable to assume what you are doing and interpret it as a interval variable, and therefore have an assumed ordering (and a distance) between different values.
What *is* problematic, though, is the fact that you are assuming a **continuous** space on a **discrete** variable. E.g., it does not make any sense to interpret the output of `4.3`, since you can only tell between `4` (Friday, assuming you start numbering your days at 0), or `5` (Saturday). Any value in between would have to be rounded, which is perfectly fine - until you want to perform backpropagation on this loss.
It is problematic, because you are essentially introducing a non-convex and non-continous function, no matter how you "round" your values. Again, to exemplify this, you could assume to round to the nearest number; then, at the value of `4.5`, you would see a sudden increase in the loss, which is non-differentialbe, and will therefore put a hard time on your optimizer, potentially limiting convergence of your system.

If, instead, you utilize several output neurons, as suggested by @venkata krishnan, you might lose the information of distance (how many days you are off) on paper, but you can of course still interpret your loss in any way you like. This would certainly be the better option for a discrete-valued variable.

**To answer your original question**: I personally would make sure that your loss function is bounded both in the upper and lower level, as you could otherwise have undefined/inconsistent loss values, that might lead to subpar optimization. One way to do this is to re-scale a Sigmoid function (the co-domain of `sigmoid(R)` is `[0,1]`. Eventually, you can then just multiply your output by `6`, to get a value range that is `[0,6]`, and could (after rounding) cover all the values you want.

Comment: so, i can use sigmoid function for this particular problem? and multiply it by 6? but isn't sigmoid function used for probability? Sorry, I'm still new to ML so I'm a little bit confused

Comment: No activation function has a direct interpretation in a probabilistic sense, it always depends on how you view your results and what you are doing with them. This is why Softmax is so popular, as it has neat mathematical properties together with Cross Entropy Loss. But yeah, you *could* use a scaled Sigmoid here, although literally *all answers advise against it*.

Comment: Also note that a simple scaling is essentially doing what you asked for in the other answer: if you suddenly change the number of days/time scale, you can still technically apply a different scale and retrain without much change.

Comment: so, sigmoid isn't mandatory for probability? hmm if so, sigmoid seems like the best way to do this, because i need more dynamic way to do it.

Comment: also another question, how do i scale up the output of the sigmoid function, do I just multiply it by max value of wanted output?

Comment: Don't worry, I more hope to have answered accordingly and shed some light on the problem. For future reference, I also want to remind you, that despite the courtesy of it, unnecessary comments (like "Thanks!" or "Me too!") can clutter up answers and make it harder for subsequent users to find the answer they are looking for. Please consider a little more whether individual comments are explicitly necessary. For your last question: you can simply do something like `return 6 * nn.Sigmoid()` (that is, if you are using PyTorch). But essentially just multiply with the max value.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is solving a classification problem with a regression approach. That's at least unconventional.

You can use any activation function you want and define your output as you want. E.g. linear, relu with output range from 1 to 7 or something between -1(or 0) and 1 like tanh or sigmoid and map the output (-1 -> 1; -0.3 -> 2; ...).

The problem for you will be that you get a floatingpoint number as a result. So your model not only has to learn how to classify correctly but also how to predict the (allmost) exact number you want in your output neuron. That makes the problem more complicated than it has to be. With a model like that it also will be likley that for some outlier datapoints you might get unexpected return values like 0, -1 or 8. What do you do then?

To sum it up: Listen to @venkata krishnan, use softmax and seven output neurons and map this result to a number between 1 and 7 outside the neural network if you have to.

**EDIT**

What comes to my mind after reading the comments again would be a mix of what you want and what you should do.

You could try to make the second last layer a 7 neuron softmax layer and map those output to a single neuron in the last layer.

Niether did i ever try that nor have i ever read about something like that so i can't tell you if thats a good idea, likely not, but you might consider it worth a try.

Comment: that make sense, yeah. So, can i for the training output make all of the output use sigmoid activation function to train and put 1 in the actual wanted day, eg 0->0 ; 1->0 ; 2->1; 3->0 ;......;6->0 ?

Comment: also, what if i wanted output more than 7 days, for example, x will hapen in 9th day from today, or 15th day from today, etc?

Comment: You could do Sigmoid, but that is usually not what you do with categorical outputs. The values actually do not matter, as long as you apply the softmax over the vector of outputs. If you haven't already, I strongly suggest you read up on the probabilistic interpretation of softmax, as for example in [this article](https://ljvmiranda921.github.io/notebook/2017/08/13/softmax-and-the-negative-log-likelihood/). It is more t view the whole of your outputs as a *probability distribution*.

Answer (score -1):

As far I know, there is no such thing like an activation function which will yield 0 to infinite. You can apply 7 output nodes with a "**Softmax**" activation function which will return the probability. There is another solution which may work. You can you 3 output nodes with "**Binary**" activation function which will return either 0 or 1. That means you can have 8 different outputs with only 3 nodes which are 000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110 and 111. You can use 7 of them.

Comment: Surely there is. The output range of ReLU is exactly what OP is mentioning. It has a value range of `[0, \infty]`. I agree with your point of view on the ouptut nodes, but you also have to realize that the probability distribution over the categorical values will lose you any information on the "distance" ( predicting Tuesday instead of Monday is arguably less bad than predicting Friday instead of Monday). You cannot recover this distance directly from a softmax, unless you also alter your loss function. On a similar node, your binary approach, while elegant, leaves the question of loss open.