# Forecasts Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, softmax

This is a follow up question from [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57720822/activation-function-to-get-day-of-week) . So, I'm making an Machine Learning Model to forecast when some things happen. I will use softmax as output.

My question is, is it better to use 7 output nodes ( range from sunday - saturday, i.e. for data on monday, then the computer predict some things will happen in friday) or 0....n output nodes ( as in day interval since day h )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the weekday doesn't have to do something with your data, it's defenetly better to use the 0....n outputnodes since day n.

In that case, which differs from what you asked last time, a single neuron with relu as output might be even better. (This time the weekday seems not to play a role, so you try not to classify the weekday (classification - discrete), but want to know the time to the next event (regression - continuous), that also could be 3.54 days).

Classification: Softmax

Regression: Single Neuron with relu/linear/...

Comment: My input consists of weekday, the date and 2 other node. Relu seems make sense for this problem, easier to train and it's regression, might worth a try. I will try softmax if relu's accuracy isn't good.

Comment: You might want to tell whats the two other inputs are, to get better feedback

Comment: it's just max size and current size

Comment: Then you have to question yourself if its possible to tell the remaning days only from those two parameters. And if it is maybe its easier to use a simple formula instead of a data driven approach.

Comment: care to elaborate what "a simple formula" is? or any example?

Comment: Its a little hard without having a clue what your data is about, but the two features `max size` and `current size` make it look like your data is about something that is growing and you are trying to predict when its reaches a specific size. Then there might be some formula like: `max_size-(current_size * α)`  where `α` is some growth factor (e.g. in `kg/day`) which discribes your growth more or less.

Comment: yeah if such a function exists and you can find it. Then it needs no AI